# Interface OnSeekBarChangeListner does not have constructor / No members to implement have been found

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, constructor

[![Not able to implement Menbers`package com.manan.musicx

import android.content.Context
import android.media.AudioManager
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.MediaController
import android.widget.SeekBar

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
lateinit var btnPlay: Button
lateinit var btnPause: Button
lateinit var btnStop: Button
lateinit var player: MediaPlayer
lateinit var sbVolume: SeekBar

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    btnPlay = findViewById(R.id.btnPlay)
    btnPause = findViewById(R.id.btnPause)
    btnStop = findViewById(R.id.btnStop)
    sbVolume = findViewById(R.id.sbVolume)

    val audioManager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager

    player = MediaPlayer.create(this@MainActivity, R.raw.music)

    val maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
    val curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)

    sbVolume.setMax(maxVolume)
    sbVolume.setProgress(curVolume)

    sbVolume.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener())

    // Play function, play set on click listner

    btnPlay.setOnClickListener {

        player.start()
    }

    // Pause function, pause set on click listner

    btnPause.setOnClickListener {

        player.pause()
    }

    // Stop function, stop set on click listner

    btnStop.setOnClickListener {

        player.stop()
    }
}
```

}`][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOh14.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOh14.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the `Seekbar.OnSeekBarChangeListener` as:

```
sbVolume.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
        //onProgressChanged
    }

    override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        //onStartTrackingTouch
    }

    override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        //onStopTrackingTouch
    }
})
```

or create a class implementing `SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener` as:

```
private class MySeekbarChangeListener : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
        //onProgressChanged
    }

    override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        //onStartTrackingTouch
    }

    override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        //onStopTrackingTouch
    }
}
```

and use it as:

```
sbVolume.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(MySeekbarChangeListener())
```